# DjangoBackendFilter and filtering by id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple filter made using DjangoBackendFilter and Ordering filter. It works with all the query parameters such as ?part_number=12345 but when it comes to the id field it does not work at all, i.e. ?id=12345.

I don't have any list filters yet so I do not expect multiple filter values to work. But I do expect every field to work for single value input. Seems strange that only the id field does not work. I have also tried using ?pk=12345 in the API URL but it does not filter anything either.

#### views.py

```
class PartList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Part.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    filter_fields = '__all__'
    ordering = 'id'
```

#### pagers.py

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'results': data
        })
```

#### serializers.py

```
class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: have you defined filter_backend class ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The problem was with

```
filter_fields = '__all__'
```

This notation includes the id/pk in the serializer but in the filter it does not include id.

So I just replaced it with

```
filter_fields = [field.name for field in Part._meta.get_fields()]
```